# IIS 8.5 MVC 5 Routes 'api/controllerName' gives 404 Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8.5

Within a **MVC 5 Webapi** project, I am trying to do a GET request via jquery using URL 'api/controllerName'. The web application is hosted under Default Website and the root of the webisite is "localhost/myApp".

The route 'api/controllerName' gets translated to 'localhost/api/controllerName' instead of 'localhost/myApp/api/controllerName' throwing **404 Not found Error**.

This has to do something with IIS 8.5 and MVC 5 routing, because:

1. The Same setup works well on IIS 7.5
2. The same set up works well on IIS 8.5 if i do not use a virtual directory and host the application directly at Default Web Site.

My Global.asax.cs's RegisterRoutes Method looks like below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Comment: If it works in the folder assigned to Default Website (by default this is 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot'), but not in a different folder, it seems you have not set up the website in IIS properly.  I do not think you can assume that if you publish your web app to c:\inet\wwwroot\myApp' that you can then access this in a browser with 'http://localhost/myApp".  Instead, you need to set up the website on e.g. a different port in the IIS Bindings dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Apparently, IIS 7.5 worked fine with the bare route 'api/controllerName' but IIS 8.5 needed a fully qualified route created using @Url.RouteURL utility with RouteName as "DefaultApi".

i replaced the URL with

```
'@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "controllerName"})'
```

and it worked like a charm (on both IIS 7.5 and IIS 8.5).